# Get list of Facebook Friends from FriendPickerFragment using SDK 3.5 in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook SDK 3.5 and i am a bit confused. If i use `FriendPickerFragment` (from their example) it populates the fragment with the list of friends, but I only want to have the JSON or list of GraphUser only.

Does anybody know how to get that information using the picker fragment. I don't understand how they get the data to populate the fragment.

This is how i can see what is selected from the populated list:

```
List<GraphUser> selectedUsers = friendPickerFragment.getSelection();
    for (GraphUser selectedUser : selectedUsers) {  System.out.println("selectedUser: " + selectedUser);
}
```

But how can i get the entire list(selected or not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a graph request to me/friends. The SDK already provides you with a convenience method in [Request.newMyFriendsRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/Request#newMyFriendsRequest%28Session,%20GraphUserListCallback%29)

Comment: With the new api 2.0, this works only for those apps which have a canvas app

Comment: I agree with Jaffa. Here is link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

Answer (score 3):

```
 Request request = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(
 Session.getActiveSession(),
 new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {

 @Override
 public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
     System.out.println("Users: " + users);
     }
            });
 request.executeAsync();
```